# want to replace Hostname but regex not matching pattern

Tags: bash, shell, replace, hostname

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Directory where this script is located
#
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

declare hosts=()

#declare host_regex='[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}'

declare host_regex = '^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$'

#declare host_regex='(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63})$'

while getopts i:h: opt
do
   case $opt in

       i)

     ;;

       h) 
      echo "Proposed Hostname $OPTARG"
      if [[ $OPTARG =~ ${host_regex} ]]; then
                # Store Hostname in array for further processingg
                hosts=$(echo $(cat "${DIR}/sample.txt") | grep -Eo ${host_regex})

                for host in ${hosts[@]}; do
                    echo "Replacing '${host}' with '${OPTARG}'"
                    sed -e 's/'${host}'/'$OPTARG'/g' "${DIR}/sample.txt"
                done
            else
                echo "Failed to update hostname"
            fi

     ;;
  esac
done
```

**i have tried following code to replace Hostname it but regex is not matching the pattern.**
I have tried all this regex specified in my code along with commented regex also

Comment: With your code, you should get a syntax error because you have a space in front and after the equal sign, when you try to assign the regexp.

Comment: no that is not problem

Comment: Any examples of how sample.txt looks like ?

Comment: @MaheshPhate: It **is** a problem. If I just copy and paste that line into bash, I get (as one would expect) an error message.